# How can I update Couchbase Lite version 1.3.1 in Objective-C to latest Couchbase Lite version 3.0?

Tags: objective-c, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am new to Couchbase lite.

I have already setup of Couchbase lite 1.3.1 in Objective-C and it's working fine. I have to upgrade this with Couchbase lite 3.0.

In latest Couchbase lite list of changes. Ex: *CBLManager is not supporting, properties object is not available in CBLDocument*  ...

**Could you please guide me how I can start this?**

Any document where I can find not supporting class, methods, properties alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that there is no documentation specifically describing how to move from 1.3.1 to 3.0.  The 1.x versions of CBL were sunset several years ago.

There is good documentation of the 3.0 version here:

https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/objc/quickstart.html

I suspect that reading that documentation would be a very good start.